# How to resolve ClassNotFound Exception while starting jboss server

Tags: jboss7.x

While starting jboss 7.1 I got following error

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

How to resolve this exception.....?
Please any one can help me to out...?

Comment: Is there more to the error? Did you change anything?

Comment: Actually I am trying to deploy liferay-portal-6.1.2-ce-ga3 bundle which comes with jboss 7.1.1 .I am using default configuration ,just have changed datasource configuration in standalone.xml(i.e all required basic configuration from dock)